# Error: Identifier "PrintGuessesRemaining" , "PrintWordSpaceDelinated" , "PrintWordsRemainingIsUndefined"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, linker, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have Created a Print Class where I have created all of those functions.

When I attempt to call these functions, I get the Identifier Error. I am sure I have incorrectly set up my class. Please Help construct Print Class

Code attached:

```
// Print.cpp - Print Class implementation
// Written by Varun Patel

#include "Print.h"

Print::Print()
{
}

Print::Print(const string& word)
{
    Word = word;
}

void Print::PrintWordsRemaining(set<string>& possibleWords_, bool  displayNumberOfWordsRemaining_)
{
    if(displayNumberOfWordsRemaining_) 
    {
        cout << "There are " << possibleWords_.size() << " possible words left." << endl;
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

}

void Print::PrintWordSpaceDelinated(string word_)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < word_.size(); i++) 
    {
        cout << word_[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Print::PrintGuessesRemaining(int guessesRemaining_)
{
    cout << "You have " << guessesRemaining_ << " guesses remaining." << endl;
}
```

Here is how i try to call one of the functions:

```
#include "UpdateGuessesRemaining.h"

void UpdateGuessesRemaining(set<string>& newPossibleWords, int& guessesRemaining, 
    char guessChar, string& guessedWord) 
{
        set<string>::iterator wordPtr = newPossibleWords.begin();
    if (wordPtr->find(guessChar) == -1) 
    {
        cout << "Sorry, incorrect guess. ";
        PrintGuessesRemaining(--guessesRemaining);
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << "Correct! The word contains " << guessChar << "." << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is my header File:

```
// Print.h - Print Class declaration
// Written by Varun Patel


#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

#include "PromptForGuessesRemaining.h"

using namespace std;

class Print
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    Print();

    Print(const string& word);

    void PrintWordsRemaining(set<string>& possibleWords, bool displayNumberOfWordsRemaining);

    void PrintWordSpaceDelinated(string word);


    void PrintGuessesRemaining(int guessesRemaining);

private:

     string Word;


};
```

Thanks For Your Help,

Varun

Comment: Please add your "print.h" file. It may contain useful information. Also, make sure the error is from the compiler, not the linker. They mean different things.

Comment: I have added my Header File- Thanks Much for taking a look at this for me!

Comment: I see you added the tag "linker-error". Is the error actually coming from the linker?

Comment: The errors i get say "Identifier Not Found" im not sure where the error is coming from but i think it is because either my Print class is incorrectly set up or i am calling the functions within the PrintClass incorrectly